# What is the meaning of (/ ... /) in Fortran

Tags: fortran

I don't know Fortran but have to inspect a part of a code written in this language. This code is full of lines similar to this:

```
matmul(recVecs2p, real((/ i1, i2, i3 /), dp))
```

I can't find semantics of `(/ ... /)` on Google, so I hope I will get an answer here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This appears to be a language feature that was introduced in Fortran 90.

A first hint is the mention of this syntax on the [Wikipedia article on Fortran 95](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fortran_95_language_features#Arrays), where it is referred to as "**array-valued constants (constructors)**".

[Chapter 4 of the Programmer's Guide to Fortran 90, 3nd [sic!] Edition](http://www.fortran.com/fortran_storenew/Html/Info/books/gd3_c04_1.html) has a little more information about `(/ … /)` in Chapter 4.1.4. (Due to the copyright statement I may not reproduce the relevant text passage here, but it's freely accessible through the above hyperlink.)

Comment: Worth adding that more recent editions of the language standard allow the use of `[` and `]` in place of `(/` and `/)`.  This is also covered at http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/fortran/996/arrays/6858/array-constructors#t=201611131712306649575

Comment: The alternative [] array constructor delimiters were included in f2003 standard.  Compilers still vary widely in the extent to which this facilitates optimization (or not).